# Laravel 5.2 Installation Error: failed opening required ../vendor/autoload.php

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I'm trying to install Laravel version 5.2. But it throws this error while installation. But if I install the latest version It works fine. I also tried updating to the latest version of PHP but still the same error. I'm using this to create a project `composer create-project laravel/laravel onetone 5.2`

```
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\onetone\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\onetone\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\onetone\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\onetone\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
PHP Warning:  require(C:\xampp\htdocs\onetone\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\onetone\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\onetone\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\onetone\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with error code 255
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following command:

You need to use the `--prefer-dist` flag and wrap version number in a quotation.

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel onetone "5.2.*"`

Answer (score 0):

php version for laravel 5.2 is between 5.5.9 - 7.1.*. so make sure that u have right php version in your computer